# Auto overwrite created thumbnail of video file in php

Tags: php, ffmpeg, thumbnails

I have successfully created thumbnail image of video file but I have some issue.This is my code for creating thumbnail of image:

```
    $ffmpeg = "C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg";
    $videoFile = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

    $imageFile = "1.jpg";
    $size = "800x420";
    $getFromSecond = 25;
    $cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $videoFile -an -ss $getFromSecond -s $size $imageFile";
    if(!shell_exec($cmd))
    {
        echo "Thumbnail Created!";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error Creating Thumbnail";
    }
```

With this code I got result `1.jpg` as given. *MY question is that* **when Second time I create the thumbnail for another video the previous one is replaced.What cant I do for this**

Comment: Why not just use a different value for `$imageFile` each time?

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie I tried so but This was given me empty file name with correct result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ffmpeg = "C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg";
    $videoFile = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    $imageFile = time().".jpg";
    $size = "300x300";
    $getFromSecond = 5;
    $cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $videoFile -an -ss $getFromSecond -s $size $imageFile";
    if(!shell_exec($cmd))
    {
        echo "Thumbnail Created!";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error Creating Thumbnail";
    }
```

**$imageFile = time().".jpg";** i have changed this line in your code,which will give you unique names according to time...